# Error: Cookies are blocked due to unexpected output. For help, please see this documentation or try the support forums

Tags: wordpress, cookies

I am getting error logging in - Error: Cookies are blocked due to unexpected output. For help, please see this documentation or try the support forums.

I used chrome, safari and firefox.

Wordpres is wp-login.php

Need help fixing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is steps to resolve issue step by step so you can follow this steps https://www.mybloggingplus.com/wordpress-cookies-blocked-unexpected-output.html